# vscode find in files auto pastes clipboard item, I want to stop this

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode if I try `find in files` vscode automatically pastes whats in the clipboard.  I want it to stop doing this, how do I do that? I tried the setting `editor.selectionClipboard` and proposed here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90222, but this does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have that item still selected in the editor?  With the setting `Seed Search String from Selection` set to `true` a selected term or closest term will seed find but not with the clipboard content.

Comment: yes this item is selected

Comment: `editor.selectionClipboard` is not a setting anymore (v1.48)